# Array separate odd and even to array of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a question.

I have a Array like below

```
WorkList1 = ["Monday", "running", "Tuesday", "swimming", "Wednesday", "riding"]
```

I expect change it like

```
WorkList2 = [{ "day": "Monday", "exercise": "running" }, 
             { "day": "Tuesday", "exercise": "swimming" },
             { "day": "Wednesday", "exercise": "riding" }]
```

but it seems got some Error, this is my code.

```
const WorkList2 = [];
const object = { "day": '', "exercise": '' };
for (let i = 0; i < WorkList1.length; i += 1) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    object['day'] = i;
  } else {
    object['exercise'] = i;
  }
  WorkList2.push(object);
}
```

I have read some thread about Array but I still have some trouble.....
Could somebody help me to figure it out? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You are assigning the value as array index `i`

```
object['day'] = i;
```

**2)** It will have as many objects as there are in `WorkList1`.

You have to skip the insertion at every odd index. What you can do is just loop over the array and increment it by `2` instead of `1` and push `data` value as `WorkList1[i]` and `exercise` as `WorkList1[i + 1]`

```js
const WorkList1 = [
  "Monday",
  "running",
  "Tuesday",
  "swimming",
  "Wednesday",
  "riding",
];

const WorkList2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < WorkList1.length; i += 2) {
  WorkList2.push({
    day: WorkList1[i],
    exercise: WorkList1[i + 1],
  });
}

console.log(WorkList2);
```

You can also try the second solution

```js
const WorkList1 = [
  "Monday",
  "running",
  "Tuesday",
  "swimming",
  "Wednesday",
  "riding",
];

const WorkList2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < WorkList1.length; i += 1) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    WorkList2.push({
      day: WorkList1[i]
    });
  } else {
    const lastObj = WorkList2[WorkList2.length - 1];
    lastObj.exercise = WorkList1[i];
  }
}

console.log(WorkList2);
```